# express.static files dont load static files

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

I am trying to server static files with express and them dont work, i think its express problem or something but i dont realize why it dont works.
my folders look like this:

app.js
public
--css
--js
--images

and the code i trying to run like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

if i do console.log of the path

```
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
```

i get the next path
C:\Users\J\Desktop\node.js\social-media-cars\public

and if i look at the path with the windows file explorer i see that the path is correct and i see the content inside, so i dont think its path fault

i also tryed  :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

and dont works, always the same things:
[image]

im desesparate with this, idk why this dont works.

code where i use it looks like this:

```
// Import the express module
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
// Instantiate an Express application
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const ActionsRouter = require('./routers/actions-router');
const UserRouter = require('./routers/user-router');
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');

// app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

//set static files that are rendered after
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//read the cookies from response
app.use(cookieparser(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
//create the req.body 
app.use(express.json());

//user
app.use("/api",UserRouter);
app.use("/useractions",ActionsRouter);


module.exports = app;
```

```
const server = app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)});
```

get the static files with every response i get

also i get this error
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to load the files? Are they images? js? css? Please provide this code as well.

Comment: images. .js files and .css files, but even with the empty folders it dont work

Comment: I assume you're loading these into a html page? How are you doing that? Can you add the important parts of the html page to your question?

Comment: @Brendan.H, thanks of your answer i found the mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **1. Add this middleware in the `index.js` or `app.js` above you set view engine**

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

### **2. Folder Structure**

```
|__public/   
    |__ css/
        |__ css files...
    |__ js/
        |__ js files...
```

**3. Import this way**

Now you set the path to the public directory you have to give the path public folder when you import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```

In the same way, you can import your JS files

## **You should now be all set up to access CSS or js as well as any file in the public directory**

Comment: This is the for serve static files on your frontend, If you want to access the inserted image via the URL let me know I'll prepare answer for that also

Comment: also, it didnt work, and yes my main thing why i want them is for the frontend

Comment: Okey so i guess their is a image in your public dir now you just want to access with URL/api

Answer (score 1):

okey i found it, i was so lost because when i try to  see the files that i got in each response on the browser, i was not getting any file,
but only when i linked  css and html it downloaded the static file, idk why this works like this,
i supposed every of /public file was atached to the response you use it or not

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

[image: see i only get the required file]

anyway if there is a way to get the file you request or not i would like to know